# I got exception in camera2basic when using emulator

Tags: android, android-camera

I got the following exception

```
12-11 16:58:35.719 2514-2514/com.example.android.camera2basic E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.camera2basic, PID: 2514
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest$Builder.set(android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest$Key, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
  at com.example.android.camera2basic.Camera2BasicFragment.lockFocus(Camera2BasicFragment.java:764)
  at com.example.android.camera2basic.Camera2BasicFragment.takePicture(Camera2BasicFragment.java:755)
  at com.example.android.camera2basic.Camera2BasicFragment.onClick(Camera2BasicFragment.java:864)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The code was working when I used the emulated camera but it is not working when I tried Webcam0

Comment: Check you have added required permissions of camera2 API

Comment: it is Android sample code :)

Comment: @Mohammed Subhi : Is this solved?